# Connect Tomcat to ActiveMQ embedded in JBoss EAP 7.2 using http-remoting Protocol

Tags: jms, jndi, spring-jms, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

I have following systems defined in my `docker-compose.yml` for better reproducibility.

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  jmstool:
    image: spx01/jmstool-activemq
    container_name: jmstool
    ports:
      - 8181:8080
    volumes:
      - ./context.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml
  jboss:
    image: daggerok/jboss-eap-7.2
    container_name: jboss
    environment:
      - PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS=-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./configure.cli:/tmp/configure.cli
```

The tool [jmstool](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-jms-client-all/2.16.0) is a Spring application deployed on a Tomcat 9 to communicate over JMS with different queues. I could get it work with a standalone activeMQ.

After startup of these containers I add an application user and two queues to messaging subsystem of the running JBoss:

```
docker exec jboss jboss-eap-7.2/bin/add-user.sh -a -u myUser -p "myPa##word"
docker exec jboss jboss-eap-7.2/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=/tmp/configure.cli
```

with content of `configure.cli`

```
connect
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=ImportantMessages:add(entries=[java:jboss/exported/ImportantMessages])
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=ImportantMessagesOut:add(entries=[java:jboss/exported/ImportantMessagesOut])
```

The `standalone-full.xml` looks good and quite similar to [this other example][2].

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
        <server name="default">
            <journal pool-files="10"/>
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
            </in-vm-connector>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
            </in-vm-acceptor>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="ImportantMessages" entries="java:jboss/exported/ImportantMessages"/>
            <jms-queue name="ImportantMessagesOut" entries="java:jboss/exported/ImportantMessagesOut"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
```

Now I try to configure this remote connection in the `context.xml` of the Spring application. I (sadly) have to use the `http-remoting` Protocol, not the connection via `tcp`.

```
<Context>
<JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllFiles="false" scanAllDirectories="false"/>

<Resource
        name="jms/ImportantMessages"
        auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
        physicalName="ImportantMessages"/>

<Resource
        name="jms/ImportantMessagesOut"
        auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
        physicalName="ImportantMessagesOut"/>

<Environment name="spring.jms.jndi-name"
             value="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
             type="java.lang.String"
             override="false"/>

<Environment name="jmstool.outgoingQueues"
             value="java:comp/env/jms/ImportantMessages"
             type="java.lang.String"
             override="false"/>

<Environment name="jmstool.incomingQueues"
             value="java:comp/env/jms/ImportantMessagesOut"
             type="java.lang.String"
             override="false"/>

</Context>
```

The exception in the jmstool log does not surprise me:

```
ackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=14, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [http-remoting]
```

This error still occurs when I add [jboss-remoting][3], [jboss-remoting3][4] or [activemq-optional][5] to Tomcat's lib folder.

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Justin's answer helped me. After adding [artemis-jms-client-all.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-jms-client-all/2.16.0) to tomcats lib file and reconfiguring the context.xml the connection could be established. Furthermore the client cannot lookup the queues because of following exception. Where can I configure the address property of the queues?

When I call

```
new JndiLocatorDelegate().lookup("java:comp/env/jms/ImportantMessages", javax.jms.Queue.class)
```

this exception is thrown

```
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: address cannot be null
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQDestination.setSimpleAddress(ActiveMQDestination.java:414)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQDestination.setAddress(ActiveMQDestination.java:399)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQDestination.buildFromProperties(ActiveMQDestination.java:540)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.JNDIStorable.setProperties(JNDIStorable.java:58)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory.getObjectInstance(JNDIReferenceFactory.java:65)
            at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
            at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
            ... 68 more
```

When I set an not empty string to `address="asdf"` of the queue defining Resource nodes, I get the exception

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'java:comp/env/jms/ImportantMessagesOut' - retrying using FixedB
ackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=9, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013:
Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
```

Comment: You need to use your own InitialContext and not the one from Tomcat, using initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080"); to create it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It helped me to fix the old problem. Now I have a new one. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that by integrating with JBoss EAP you're not working with ActiveMQ 5.x. You're working with ActiveMQ Artemis. Therefore you need to use the integration classes from ActiveMQ Artemis, e.g.:

```xml
<Context>
<JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllFiles="false" scanAllDirectories="false"/>

<Resource
        name="jms/ImportantMessages"
        auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
        address="ImportantMessages"/>

<Resource
        name="jms/ImportantMessagesOut"
        auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
        address="ImportantMessagesOut"/>

<Resource
        name="jms/connectionFactory"
        auth="Container"
        userName="myUser"
        password="myPa##word"
        type="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
        brokerURL="tcp://jboss:8080?httpEnabled=true"/>

<Environment name="jmstool.outgoingQueues"
             value="java:comp/env/jms/ImportantMessages"
             type="java.lang.String"
             override="false"/>

<Environment name="jmstool.incomingQueues"
             value="java:comp/env/jms/ImportantMessagesOut"
             type="java.lang.String"
             override="false"/>

</Context>
```

This is discussed in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation on Tomcat integration.](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/tomcat.html)

Take note of the `httpEnabled=true` on the connection factory's `brokerURL`. This is an important parameter which enables the client to use the `http-acceptor` defined on JBoss EAP.

Also, be sure to include the [artemis-jms-client-all.jar](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-jms-client-all/2.16.0/jar) with your application.

You can potentially get an equivalent solution using the JNDI implementation from JBoss EAP (i.e. `org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory`). Generally speaking this would be the recommended approach when integrating JMS with JBoss EAP. However, the aforementioned `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory` provides simple, direct integration with Tomcat. Furthermore, I've not confirmed that using JBoss EAP JNDI is actually possible in this scenario, and it's almost certainly more complicated than the direct integration I outlined above.

Comment: Hello Justin, thank you a lot for your answer! Now I'm not getting the above errors any more. Instead I get a different exception - I mentioned it in the post.

Comment: The issue with the address was caused because I didn't change the XML properly to use `address` instead of `physicalName`. I've updated my answer (along with the changes you suggested). I'm not sure at this point what the `ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException` could be. Does your client implementation match the version of ActiveMQ Artemis used by JBoss EAP?

Comment: Hello, sorry for late reply. I confirmed that I have the same error when using Version 2.9.0 on server and client side.

Comment: I solved it now using your configuration from above together with the openwire protocol over 61616.